# Matlab's JDBC/ODBC SQL behaviour differs from Access 2010

Tags: matlab, ms-access

This is a hybrid question & public service announcement.  The basic question is whether there are convenient and/or efficient workarounds to the limitations listed below.  I spent half the morning discovering that one cannot just transplant SQL code from Access to Matlab.  I've boiled it down to 3 points so far.

1. Can't use double quotes in SQL statements to avoid collision with
   Matlab's string delimiter.  The Matlab code for the SQL code strings
   can become quite complicated, especially if the SQL strings already
   use repeated single-quotes to represent a single quote within a
   string constant.
2. Must always specify a source table from which to query.  What won't
   work is "SELECT #2015-07-28#".  One basically needs to create a 1-row dummy table.
3. Must always select at least one field in the table being queried. 
   An asterisk does not seem to suffice.

The above limitations do not exist when submitting SQL code using the Access Query Designer (either in SQL 92 mode or not), nor do these limitations exist when submitting SQL code using VBA via CurrentProject.Connection.Execute.

Hopefully, this saves someone else some time in learning about these differences.  And if anyone has found a workaround, that would be appreciated.  Note that the above is in the context of using the JDBC/ODBC bridge (3rd of 3 illustrated configurations in the [drivers documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/database/ug/choosing-between-odbc-and-jdbc-drivers.html).  The database toolbox documentation for directly connecting to an Access file using code (rather than setting up a data source using the GUI) only describes a code pattern that uses the JDBC/ODBC bridge.  This is described in Example "Connect to Microsoft Access Using a File DSN" in the ["Connect to database"](http://www.mathworks.com/help/database/ug/database.html#bt1gv4p) page.  I'd like to stick to this approach because I want to quickly be able to directly specify the source *.accdb file without jumping through GUI hoops of setting up a data source.

I've posted this to:

- [Stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31682827/matlabs-jdbc-odbc-sql-behaviour-differs-from-access-2010)
- [Usenet](http://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/comp.soft-sys.matlab/xnTbSDyF5Aw)

Answer (score 0):

While I have not connected Matlab to Access, I have connected Access databases to PHP, Python, SAS, R, even Excel without any issues with quotes or asterisk. As for the needed source table in queries that is simply due to the Jet/ACE SQL dialect as each dialect have their particular rules. But your query above should work for one-row, one-column output of such date. SQL Server does not require a source table but Oracle does. Access dates are in the `MM/DD/YYYY` format, requiring `#` in conditional statements. MySQL use dates in `YYYY-MM-DD` format, requiring single quotes.

Are you using Windows installed Jet/ACE ODBC drivers? Do note these drivers are softwares external to any application (not part of Access) and can be used by any client interfacing to any data source. Aside - many are not aware that Access' backend database engine, Jet/ACE is actually a Windows technology and not restricted to Access; PC users without Access installed can still use this engine. Hence, [connection strings](https://www.connectionstrings.com/access-2010/) are standard across ODBC calls. And as I see you can apply same principles to [Matlab database connections](http://www.mathworks.com/help/database/ug/database.html).

With that said, my suggestions/workarounds:

- properly learn the SQL dialect for connecting database and check if query runs; even optimize or re-write as needed
- try escaping various punctuation not compliant in Matlab strings or use the ASCII counterparts: `chr(34)` for double quote; `chr(39)` for single quote; `chr(42)` for asterisk.
- if select statements are limited in Matlab strings, create a temp table from query (use make-table query `SELECT * INTO newtable FROM query` outside of Matlab), then connect to this new table
- use intermediary coding language (VBA, Python, C#) by user trigger or
  command line to connect to database and export needed dataset, then
  automate Matlab to import
- export query to flatfile format (csv, txt, etc.) for Matlab import

Comment: In the question, I clarified that JDBC/ODBC is the 3rd of 3 driver configs. My point#2 was more about needing a source table rather than literal date formats. About attributing the differences to the Jet/ACE dialect, I would have tried the "Windows native" ODBC config, but the "Connect to database" page that I cite only provides a detailed "URL" for the JDBC/ODBC config.

Comment: I appreciate that the differences can be worked around by simply changing the SQL, using temp tables, and other languages, but I was really hoping that there was a way to enable the use of SQL as typed into Access, e.g., if it is using the native ODBC driver, where would I find the "URL" for that? P.S. Thanks for your initial answer. It showed me how I could clean up the question.